# Is it possible to decode and recompile flash using c#?

Tags: .net, flash

I'd like to decode a SWF file into its base FLA file and then recompile that back into an SWF.  Can this be done using C#?

Comment: You can decompile a swf into abc(actionscript bytecode), and modify that. why would you use the base FLA ?

Comment: Hmm actually that might work.  Can you point me to something that would show me how to do that using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fla format changes every version of the Flash IDE but really it is just a container, I would suggest looking into the CS5 uncompressed fla format which will be easer to generate but you still need all of the byte code out of the swf, I would look at the actionScript library http://github.com/claus/as3swf for the basics but you are still going to need to write a conversion layer back into the fla.

Comment: Do you know of anything written in .NET?  do you know if this can even be done in .Net?  I think that link is a good start but I would prefer something in a language i'm familiar with if it exists